# Boolean evaluation error: Incompatible types

Tags: delphi, variables, boolean, delphi-7, pascal

I am trying to set a boolean variable (curs) to false in my code but I am getting this error:

> [Error] Main.pas(50): Incompatible types

Does anyone know what this means?

```
if form1.Left = pt.X and form1.Top = pt.Y
then curs := false;
```

If you know or have any ideas on what happened please feel free to share. :) thanks

-connorbp

Comment: Show us more code, specifically the definition of `curs`, and also tell us which is line 50.

Comment: This would be nice re-worded to be more generic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because you need to put the equality check between parentheses, like so:

```
if ( form1.Left = pt.X ) and ( form1.Top = pt.Y ) then
  curs := false;
```